# SQL query issue with wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, sorting, date, plugins

I have a form along with CFDB plugin (contact form DB). I have a plugin to query this data for the current user and plot it, but my sorting isn't working.

Here is the query (looking for last 15 entries by entered date, not date entered):

```
SELECT
MAX(IF(field_name='number-sleep', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Sleep',
MAX(IF(field_name='date-sleep', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Date7',
MAX(IF(field_name='Submitted Login', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Login7'
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE 
form_name = 'Sleep' 
GROUP BY submit_time HAVING Login7 = {{{user_login}}}
ORDER BY DATE('Date7') desc
LIMIT 15
```

It doesn't sort correctly (changing desc to asc does nothing). What am I doing wrong? Is the date field not entering database as a date?

Comment: Can you show an example, how is it sorted currently and what do you desire to achieve?

Comment: I think I have found the issue. The date was in a string. But I can't figure out where to put the STR_TO_DATE command. Here is what I tried but it didn't work.

    SELECT
    MAX(IF(field_name='number-sleep', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Sleep',
    MAX(IF(field_name='date-sleep', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Date7',
    MAX(IF(field_name='Submitted Login', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Login7'
    FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
    WHERE 
    form_name = 'Sleep' 
    GROUP BY submit_time HAVING Login7 = {{{user_login}}}
    ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE('Date7','%m/%d/%Y') DESC LIMIT 15

Comment: Just a useful tip if you want to be into databases: **never, ever, EVER store date as string!** There are several great functions and other support for date formats, doing that by hand is utterly time-consuming. You want to make your life easier by using SQL, after all ;)

Comment: Either way, welcome to Stack Overflow! By focusing on more precise approach of describing your question, you can ease our job in the future.